# Python: Unpack a list of objects to Dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a list of objects that need to be unpacked to a dictionary efficiently. There are more than 2,000,000 objects in the list. The operation takes more than 1.5 hours complete. I would like to know if this can be done more efficiently. 
The objects in the list is based on this class.

```
class ResObj:
def __init__(self, index, result):
    self.loc = index ### This is the location, where the values should go in the final result dictionary
    self.res = result ### This is a dictionary that has values for this location.

    self.loc = 2
    self.res = {'value1':5.4, 'value2':2.3, 'valuen':{'sub_value1':4.5, 'sub_value2':3.4, 'sub_value3':7.6}}
```

Currently I use this method to perform this operation.

```
def make_final_result(list_of_results):
    no_sub_result_variables = ['value1', 'value2']
    sub_result_variables = ['valuen']
    sub_value_variables = ['sub_value1', 'sub_value3', 'sub_value3']

    final_result = {}
    num_of_results = len(list_of_results)
    for var in no_sub_result_variables:
        final_result[var] = numpy.zeros(num_of_results)
    for var in sub_result_variables:
        final_result[var] = {sub_var:numpy.zeros(num_of_results) for sub_var in sub_value_variables}

    for obj in list_of_results:
        i = obj.loc
        result = obj.res
        for var in no_sub_result_variables:
            final_result[var][i] = result[var]
        for var in sub_result_variables:
            for name in sub_value_variables:
                try:
                    final_result[var][name][i] = result[var][name]
                except KeyError as e:
                    ##TODO Add a debug check
                    pass
```

I have tried using multiprocessing.Manager().dict and Manager().Array() to use parallelism for this, however, I could only get 2 processes to work (even though, I manually set the processes to # of CPUs = 24). 
Can you please help me to use a faster method to improve the performance. 
Thank you.

Comment: A lot of this doesn't look like good use of data structures or particularly efficient object initialization to me, but it's really hard to tell where you started from this. Can you give example input and output please?

Comment: Please post a short, self-contained `.py` file which takes more than 1.5 hours to run on your machine: http://sscce.org/

Comment: You seem to have nested loops: `for var in no_sub_result_variables:` and `for var in sub_result_variables:`. Do you really want to have nested loops here? If yes, please rename the inner loop variable to `var2` for clarification.

Comment: I am unable to put a self-contained example as the resultant list is constructed using an ipyparallel set of jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Having nested numpy arrays doesn't seem the best way to structure your data. You can use numpy's [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) to create a more intuitive data structure.

```
import numpy as np

# example values
values = [
    {
        "v1": 0,
        "v2": 1,
        "vs": {
            "x": 2,
            "y": 3,
            "z": 4,
        }
    },
    {
        "v1": 5,
        "v2": 6,
        "vs": {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 8,
            "z": 9,
        }
    }
]

def value_to_record(value):
    """Take a dictionary and convert it to an array-like format"""
    return (
        value["v1"],
        value["v2"],
        (
            value["vs"]["x"],
            value["vs"]["y"],
            value["vs"]["z"]
        )
    )

# define what a record looks like -- f8 is an 8-byte float
dtype = [
    ("v1", "f8"),
    ("v2", "f8"),
    ("vs", [
        ("x", "f8"),
        ("y", "f8"),
        ("z", "f8")
    ])
]           

# create actual array
arr = np.fromiter(map(value_to_record, values), dtype=dtype, count=len(values))

# access individual record
print(arr[0]) # prints (0.0, 1.0, (2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
# access specific value
assert arr[0]['vs']['x'] == 2
# access all values of a specific field
print(arr['v2']) # prints [ 1.  6.]
assert arr['v2'].sum() == 7
```

Using this way of generating the data created a 2,000,000 long array in 2 seconds on my machine.

To make it work for your `ResObj` objects then sort them by the `loc` attribute, and then pass the `res` attribute to the `value_to_record` function.

Answer (score 1):

You you can distribute the work among processes by key names.
Here I create a pool of workers and pass to them var and optional subvar names.
The huge dataset is shared with workers using cheap `fork`.
`Unpacker.unpack` picks the specified vars from ResObj and returns them as an np.array
The main loop in make_final_result combines the arrays in final_result.
**Py2**:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import numpy as np

class ResObj(object):
    def __init__(self, index=None, result=None):
        self.loc = index ### This is the location, where the values should go in the final result dictionary
        self.res = result ### This is a dictionary that has values for this location.

        self.loc = 2
        self.res = {'value1':5.4, 'value2':2.3, 'valuen':{'sub_value1':4.5, 'sub_value2':3.4, 'sub_value3':7.6}}

class Unpacker(object):
    @classmethod
    def cls_init(cls, list_of_results):
        cls.list_of_results = list_of_results

    @classmethod
    def unpack(cls, var, name):

        list_of_results = cls.list_of_results
        result = np.zeros(len(list_of_results))
        if name is None:
            for i, it in enumerate(list_of_results):
                result[i] = it.res[var]
        else:
            for i, it in enumerate(list_of_results):
                result[i] = it.res[var][name]
        return var, name, result

#Pool.map doesn't accept instancemethods so the use of a wrapper
def Unpacker_unpack((var, name),):
    return Unpacker.unpack(var, name)


def make_final_result(list_of_results):
    no_sub_result_variables = ['value1', 'value2']
    sub_result_variables = ['valuen']
    sub_value_variables = ['sub_value1', 'sub_value3', 'sub_value3']

    pool = Pool(initializer=Unpacker.cls_init, initargs=(list_of_results, ))
    final_result = defaultdict(dict)

    def key_generator():
        for var in no_sub_result_variables:
            yield var, None
        for var in sub_result_variables:
            for name in sub_value_variables:
                yield var, name

    for var, name, result in pool.imap(Unpacker_unpack, key_generator()):
        if name is None:
            final_result[var] = result
        else:
            final_result[var][name] = result
    return final_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print make_final_result([ResObj() for x in xrange(10)])
```

Ensure that you are not on Windows. It lacks `fork` and multiprocessing will have to pipe entire dataset to each of 24 worker processes.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove some indentation to make your loops non-nested:

```
for obj in list_of_results:
    i = obj.loc
    result = obj.res
    for var in no_sub_result_variables:
        final_result[var][i] = result[var]
    for var in sub_result_variables:
        for name in sub_value_variables:
            try:
                final_result[var][name][i] = result[var][name]
            except KeyError as e:
                ##TODO Add a debug check
                pass
```